# Insert missing newline characters when only CR is used

Tags: shell

I have a binary program that outputs intermediate results on the terminal and always rewrites that line. Internally, it probably uses something like `system("echo -e '\rsome_useful_number')`.

So what I see and want to record is (sequentially):
`data 1`, `data 2`, `data 3`, ...

What I get when I run `./program | tee log.txt`, `./program>log.txt`, etc. as part of a script is just `last_result`.

How can I adapt my script to "insert" the missing newline characters?

Comment: You can do: `./program | tr '\r' '\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CR means "go back to the beginning of the current line".
Therefore the next line is overwriting the previous line. That means that all lines are there but only the last is visible.

Running `less log.txt` instead of `cat log.txt` should show you something like:

```
first_line^Mnext_line^Mlast_line
```

As @anubhava said:
`./program | tr '\r' '\n' | tee log.txt` or `./program | tr '\r' '\n' >log.txt` will fix this before writing to the file, or just use `cat log.txt | tr '\r' '\n'` to view the file.

P.S.: Actually you should use `tr '\r' '\n' < log.txt` to avoid a [UUoC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)-Award :)

**Update:**

When the program outputs to stderr the stderr has to be added to the stdout first:

```
./program 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n' | tee log.txt
```

And finally if you want to keep the original CR output on the console's stderr:

```
./program 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr | tr '\r' '\n' > log.txt
```

Comment: Turns out my program was outputting to stderr and not to stdout, so the solution did not work out of the box. Thanks.